# oauth2-mock-server send profile id

Tags: oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to test a OAuth2 passport setup and I found this package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2-mock-server
I'm trying to return a profile object using it but with no success.

Has anyone used this package ?
How would I pass back a profile object ?

**My mock setup:**

```
    const { OAuth2Server } = require("oauth2-mock-server");
    const request = require("request");
    
    async function startServer() {
      let server = new OAuth2Server();
      await server.issuer.keys.generate("RS256");
      await server.start(3003, "localhost");
    
      server.service.once("beforeResponse", (tokenEndpointResponse, req) => {
        console.log("tokenEndpointResponse = ", tokenEndpointResponse);
        tokenEndpointResponse.body = {
          ...tokenEndpointResponse.body,
          scope: { profile: { id: "xxx" } },
        };
      });
    
      server.service.once(
        "beforeAuthorizeRedirect",
        (authorizeRedirectUri, req) => {
          console.log("THIS WAS TRIGGERED >>>> = ", authorizeRedirectUri);
        }
      );
    }
startServer();
```

**My OAuth2Strategy**

```
const strategy = new OAuth2Strategy(
  {
    state: true,
    authorizationURL: `${process.env.MOCK_AUTH_SERVER_URL}/authorize`,
    tokenURL: `${process.env.MOCK_AUTH_SERVER_URL}/token`,
    clientID: "xxx",
    clientSecret: "xxx",
    callbackURL: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/callback`,
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
  async (accessToken, refershToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log("profile = ", profile);
    if (profile) {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
}
);
```

I keep getting back a string for profile but wanted the profile object ??